# Mongoengine получить обьект по ссылке

Tags: python, mongodb

Есть ли простой способ получить объект по ссылке при экспорте в JSON? (Не переопределяя to_json метод)

```
class RefExample(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()

class Example(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    code = db.ReferenceField(RefExample, required=True)

class RootExample(db.Document):
    Examples = db.ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Example))

RootExample.objects.to_json()
```

В Examples ссылки, а мне нужены объекты по этой ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить данные из Ref-поля, надо вызвать `__getattr__`. При стандартной сериализации, все поля преобразуются к примитивам, и в реф-поле попадает только id. Самый простой способ - написать функцию, которая будет вызывать для каждого поля документа `getattr` и записывать его в словарь под нужным ключом. Ну и вызывать эту же функцию рекурсивно для значений поля, чтобы все данные из реф-полей попали в результат.

Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой, написал класс-сериализатор:

https://gist.github.com/bromzh/ca30fb7eb5983fe5b8d6

Comment: Я скорее надеялся на недокументированный параметр)
Я для себя переопределил to_json()